# Get WorkManager instance in a ContentProvider

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I want to schedule a task in a content provider:

```
class LogProvider : ContentProvider() {
    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        Log.i("Lagg", "Initializing LogCollection")
        return try {
            context?.let { LogCollectionInitializer().initializeCollector(it) }
            true
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Where the initializer schedules a work:

```
WorkManager.getInstance()
                .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                        CleanLogDatabaseTask.DB_CLEANER_TASK_NAME,
                        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                        PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<CleanLogDatabaseTask>(DB_CLEANING_INTERVAL, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, PeriodicWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                .build()
                )
```

The problem is I get this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: WorkManager is not initialized properly.  The most likely cause is that you disabled WorkManagerInitializer in your manifest but forgot to call WorkManager#initialize in your Application#onCreate or a ContentProvider.
```

- No, I did not disable WorkManager init. What exactly is causing this problem?

Should I act differently when I'm accessing workManager from a content provider?

Comment: please check https://medium.com/@programmerr47/custom-work-manager-initialization-efdd2afa6459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know, WorkManager has it's own content provider. So if you override it and set it's priority higher, it will be initialized before other providers. so here:

````
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            android:initOrder="11"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" /> ```
````